# XSLT 2.0: How can I use the starts-with function between two sequences?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I receive a sequence of Codes of which I do not know which ones are "wildcard" codes and which are complete codes. In my example below Code '1234' is a "wildcard" code and Code '5678' is a complete code. So, I need the xslt that will return all Procedures having a Code that starts with 1234 or is equal to Code 5678. I know the starts-with xslt function cannot be applied to a sequence. I have tried many variations of for-each, all to no avail. Any suggestions?

Sorry if I was not clear, I do not know which Codes are wildcard and which are complete. A "starts-with" function would match Procedure codes starting with a specified code and also Procedure codes that exactly match a specified code. The Codes I provided were an example of what I am receiving, 1234 and 5678 can both be wildcards or neither, etc...

Codes XML:

```
<Codes>
  <Code>1234</Code>
  <Code>5678</Code>
</Codes>
```

Procedures XML:

```
<Procedures>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>12345678</Code>
  </Procedure>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>5678</Code>
  </Procedure>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>91011</Code>
  </Procedure>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>12348765</Code>
  </Procedure>
</Procedures>
```

What I need to return is the following:

```
<Procedures>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>12345678</Code>
  </Procedure>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>5678</Code>
  </Procedure>
  <Procedure>
    <Code>12348765</Code>
  </Procedure>
</Procedures>
```

Comment: If you don't know which code is complete and which is  a "wildcard", then how should the code know that?

Comment: A "starts-with" function would return those Codes starting with a specified string and also match Codes that are identical to the specified string.

Comment: So basically your question should read *"I need the xslt that will return all Procedures having a Code that starts with 1234 or starts with Code 5678 or starts with any other code listed in Codes.xml"*?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to ignore the confusing distinction between complete codes and "wildcard" codes, and concentrate on the underlying question, which is: how to apply the `starts-with()` function when you have multiple starting strings to check against.

IOW, we are looking for a way to select `Procedure` nodes whose `Code` starts with **any** of the codes listed in Codes.xml.

This can be done simply by reversing the point of view:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-codes" select="'Codes.xml'"/>

<xsl:template match="/Procedures">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Procedure">
            <xsl:variable name="current-code" select="Code" />
            <xsl:if test="document($path-to-codes)/Codes/Code[starts-with($current-code, .)]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think it can be simplified to use `<xsl:copy-of select="Procedure[some $c in document($path-to-codes)/Codes/Code satisfies starts-with($c, Code)]"/>`. And I would move `document($path-to-codes)/Codes/Code` into a variable for clarity.

Comment: @Michael Kay - nice and sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly you are looking for, but I think this should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="inputCodes">
    <Codes>
      <Code>1234</Code>
      <Code>5678</Code>
    </Codes>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:variable name="wildcard" select="$inputCodes/Codes/Code[1]"/>
  <xsl:variable name="complete" select="$inputCodes/Codes/Code[2]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Procedure[not(Code=$complete or starts-with(Code,$wildcard))]"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZE

Comment: I don't know which Codes are wildcard and which are complete.

Comment: If you don't know, then how should we know? There's something I don't get...

Comment: That's the problem I am trying to solve. I can have a sequence of 100s of Codes, some can be used to match the beginning of the Procedure code some can be used to match exactly. I first attempted starts-with($procedureCodes, $codes) but it does not support sequences per Saxon documentation.
starts-with($arg1 as xs:string?, $arg2 as xs:string?) ➔ xs:boolean

Answer (score 0):

One way to realize this is this XSLT-2.0 stylesheet (The first file with the restrictions is named `Codes.xml`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="wildcard" select="doc('Codes.xml')/Codes/Code[1]" />
  <xsl:variable name="complete" select="doc('Codes.xml')/Codes/Code[2]" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Procedure" />
    
    <xsl:template match="Procedure[starts-with(Code,$wildcard) or Code=$complete]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is as expected:

```
<Procedures>
    <Procedure>
        <Code>12345678</Code>
    </Procedure>
    <Procedure>
        <Code>5678</Code>
    </Procedure>
    <Procedure>
        <Code>12348765</Code>
    </Procedure>
</Procedures>
```

The above stylesheet defines two variables for "wildcard" and "complete" string values. Then it copies all other elements with the *identity template* and omits all `Procedure` elements except for the ones acknowleged in the last template which realize the wanted conditions.

Comment: I don't know which Codes are wildcard and which are complete.